# Is List-Comprehension any better than List-Abstractions?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, list-comprehension

Why do people prefer list comprehensions like
`(for [x '(1 2 3)] (* 2 x))` instead of  `(map #(* %1 2) '(1 2 3))`?

Are there benefits to this kind of programming?
1. Is it more readable?
2. Is it faster in some cases?
3. Is it better for certain kinds of operations and data structures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your given example, there are no benefits; but in general, `for` is useful when you're joining two (or more) sequences, or when you need to do some filtering - a `for` with `:let` and `:when` is usually more readable than a chain of nested `map` and `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

> List comprehensions are merely
>   "syntactic sugar" over standard
>   functional programs but they give an
>   intuitive reading of common operations
>   over lists. -- Guy Lapalme

Their only intent is better readability. Don't expect any significant performance improvement by using them.

[This](http://rali.iro.umontreal.ca/Publications/urls/LapalmeLispComp.pdf) paper give some insights into implementing List comprehensions in Lisp like languages.

Answer (score 1):

### Some general thoughts

First of all, list comprehensions are just syntactic sugar, so there should be no inherent difference apart from readability.

But note that list comprehensions actually **unify** at least three higher-order functions, namely `map`, `filter` and `concatMap` into *one* syntax. So in non-trivial cases where one would need complex combinations of these, the syntax can have big readability advantages.

Besides that, one can conveniently use value bindings to store results and make things even clearer:

```
[ (x, y) | x <- [1..10],
           y <- [1..10], 
           let dist = (x - 5)² + (y - 5)²,
           dist < 10² ]
```

But anyway, list comprehensions can be made much more general than just processing lists. Basically, they can process any [`Monad`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418106/how-much-is-there-to-linq/1418176#1418176) using a  uniform and convenient syntax. F# for example even extends this into controlling arbitrary programm flows.

Secondly, being even more abstract than the usual higher-order functions, list comprehensions *could* actually be faster, because the compiler can take advantage of optimization laws that would otherwise be up to the programmer to be considered.

```
[ x + 1 | x <- numbers, even x ]
```

The straightforward translation would be

```
map (\x -> x + 1) (filter even x)
```

where the list is iterated through *twice*, producing a worthless intermediate result.

The compiler however could recogize and optimize the above pattern and produce a direct, optimized `filterMap` version.

Answer (score 0):

list comprehensions are used for cases where you need to iterate through sequences in more complex ways. in your example they are the same so I would recoment map because its easier to read.

map <s>cant</s> gets ugly for <s>do</s> this for example:

```
(for [x '(1 2 3) y '(3 2 1)] (* 2 x y))
```

Comment: A single `map` cannot, but `mapcat` can. In general, it is always possible to replace a list comprehension with some combination of `map`, `mapcat`, `filter`, and `take-while`. It's just the result can be very hard to read for more complicated cases.

Comment: no though it does not do the same thing as the for above. I believe you could drop the (list and just use map to get the same effect as this. the code in the exmaple iterates through all combinations of x and y. like 2 nested for loops in java.

Comment: You are correct. We need two maps to do those nested loop things. So is it just about making your codes more readable? What do the list comprehensions expand to?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a Clojure question, but the book "Programming in Scala" by Martin Odersky, et al, has a nice discussion about how `for` comprehensions map to the `map` and `filter` functions.