# What technique in functional programming is difficult to learn but useful afterwards?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

This question is of course inspired by [Monads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) in Haskell.

Comment: after a term of monads in haskell, i still don't get it. <<shudders>>

Answer (score 8):

wrapping my head around continuation passing style has helped my javascript coding a lot

Answer (score 6):

I would say [First-class functions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)

> In computer science, a programming
>   language is said to support
>   first-class functions (or function
>   literals) if it treats functions as
>   first-class objects. Specifically,
>   this means that the language supports
>   constructing new functions during the
>   execution of a program, storing them
>   in data structures, passing them as
>   arguments to other functions, and
>   returning them as the values of other
>   functions. This concept doesn't cover
>   any means external to the language and
>   program (metaprogramming), such as
>   invoking a compiler or an eval
>   function to create a new function.

Comment: not just useful but powerful. For example you can simulate OOP even if the language doesn't support it. See for example: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: Not really difficult, in my opinion...Monads are surely an order of magnitude harder...

Comment: Doesn't seem like such a foreign concept to me either. Perhaps adding the concept of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying to this answer would spice it up a little bit.

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to measure the usefulness in connection with functional-programming itself or programming in general?

In general, the positive experience of functional programming doesn't result from particular techniques but from the way it changes your thinking -

- Holding immutable data
- Formulating declaratively (recursion, pattern-matching)
- Treating functions as data

So I'd say that functional programming is the answer to your question itself.

But to give a more specific answer too, I'd vote for functional abstraction mechanisms like

- monads
- [arrows](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows)
- continuation-passing-style
- [zippers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers)
- higher-order-functions
- generics + typeclasses.

As already said, they are very **abstract** things on the first view, but once you have understood them, they are extremely cool and valueable techniques to write concise, error-safe and last but not least **highly reusable** code.

Compare the following (Pseudocode):

```
// Concrete
def sumList(Data : List[Int]) = ...

// Generic
def sumGeneric[C : Collection[T], T : Num](Data : C) = ...
```

The latter might be somewhat unintuitive compared with the first definition, but it allows you to work with any collection and numeric type in general!

All in all, many modern (mainstream) languages have discovered such benefits and introduced very functional features like lambda functios or [Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418106/how-much-is-there-to-linq/1418176#1418176). Having understood these techniques will also improve writing code in this languages.

Comment: I agree with the first five of your suggestions, but #6 (generics) is not specific to functional programming languages - even e.g. Java supports type parameters with bounds and thus could express your sumGeneric just like above.

Answer (score 3):

One from the "advanced" department: Programming with phantom types (sometimes also called indexed types). It's admittedly not a "standard" technique in functional programming but not entirely esoteric either, and it's something to keep your brain busy for awhile (you asked for something difficult, right? ;)).

In a nutshell, it is about parameterizing types to encode and statically enforce certain properties at compile time. One of the standard examples is the vector addition function that statically ensures that given two vectors of length N and M will return a vector of length N+M or otherwise you get a compile-time error. Yes, there are more interesting applications.

These techniques are not quite as useful in C++ as they are in a proper functional programming language, but so far I've managed to sneak some of this stuff in all of my recent projects at work to a varying degree, most recently in a C++ EDSL context where it worked out really well. You don't necessarily have to encode fancy stuff, learning this helped me catching the situations where a few type tags can reduce the verbosity of an EDSL or allowed a cleaner syntax, for example.

Admittedly, the usefulness is somewhat restricted by language support and what you're trying to achieve.

Some starters:

[Generic and Indexed Type (slides with some brief applications overview)](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/wg21/meeting62/gibbons-indexed.pdf)

[Fun with Phantom Types](http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~ralf/publications/With.pdf)

The Kennedy and Russo paper mentioned in the slides is [Generalized Algebraic Data Types
and Object Oriented Programming](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/gadtoop.pdf) and puts some of this stuff into the context of C#/Java.

Chapter 3 in Dave Abraham's book [C++ Template Metaprogramming](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/) is [available online as sample chapter](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/metafunctions.pdf) and uses these techniques in C++ for dimensional analysis.

A practical FP project using phantom types is HaskellDB.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that [Structural typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) in OCaml is particularly rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

recursion. Difficult to wrap your head around it at times

Comment: Indeed. See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438558/what-techniqie-in-functional-programming-is-difficult-to-learn-but-useful-afterwa/1438569#1438569

Comment: laugh(); void laugh() { print("ha"); laugh(); }    Although this would result in something akin the name of this site eventually ;^)

Comment: Not if you're language supports tail recursion. ;)

Comment: @reinier: Looks like tail recursion to me. With many compilers, you've only created an infinite loop!

Comment: even in c? That was the syntax I was going for

Answer (score 1):

The concept of higher-order functions, lambda functions and the power of generic algorithms that are easy to combine were very beneficial for me. I'm always excited when I see what I can do with a fold in haskell.
Likewise my programming in C# has changed a lot (to the better, I hope) since I got into functional programming (haskell specifically).